# смена временной зоны web-драйвера Сhrome Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

**Задача**
Необходимо при открытии сайта через драйвер сменить текущую временную зону на другую.

**Что пробовал, и не работает для меня**

DesiredCapabilities

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities['browserstack.timezone'] = 'New_York'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Через переменную окружения

```
os.environ["TZ"] = "America/New_York"
```

Answer (score 1):

> На сколько я знаю способ которым вы пытаетесь изменить подходит только
> для FireFox и работает только на Linux.

Могу предложить сделать через расширение js-oм, либо запускать в Docker и менять таймзону в контейнере, еще вариант использовать Selenoid(хотя он тоже работает через Docker c:), там уже есть фитча для этого.
Выбирайте )

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, но я в многопоточном режиме запускаю несколько драйверов, и это точно сделать как-то можно так как есть расширение для хром, которое делает это.

Comment: тогда Selenoid идеально подходит для вас

Comment: многопоток + изоляция + более точная конфигурация если нет, то могу вам сделать расширение

Comment: а можно подробнее про то, что вы написали?

Comment: selenoid разворачивает сессии с драйверами в контейнерах докера при этом у вас есть vnc доступ к ним. Каждый контейнер изолирован, что позволяет разделить данные сессий между собой.

Comment: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/ вот тут можете подробнее просмотреть все возможности.

Comment: Спасибо, но странно что нет более простого решения данной проблемы, а если через расширение для Chrome это сделать?

Comment: да, это вполне возможно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120210/discussion-between-garrythehotdog-and-rolles).

Answer (score 0):

Данную задачу можно решить с помощью [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
tz_params = {'timezoneId': 'Asia/Omsk'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setTimezoneOverride', tz_params)
```